# Clases Anidadas miembros estáticos

Tags: java

tengo este código por poner un ejemplo:

```
class F {
    class G {
        private static int var1 = 2;
    }
}
```

La sentencia static da error y me muestra un mensaje que dice que una clase interna no puede tener miembros estáticos. Por qué es esto así? No entiendo la lógica de esto.

Gracias anticipadas.

Un saludo cordial.

Answer (score 1):

Un clase interna no puede tener miembro estáticos, a no ser que la propia clase sea estática. Piensa en ello y verás lo sencillo que es.

En el caso que muestras para acceder a la clase interna debes crear una instancia de la clase externa y luego crear una instancia de la clase interna. Es decir los miembros estáticos quedan inservibles ya que no son miembros de la e¡instancia sino de la clase. Es mas - los miembros de una clase interna no son accesibles desde la clase externa. ¿Qué sentido tiene de tener un miembro estático si no hay forma de accederlo? En la propia inner class lo puedes acceder, desde la outer - no. Para qué hacerlo estático???

Ahora, si hace la inner class estática... a lo mejor cosas cambian un poco. Pero la clase externa debe ser pública. Es lo mismo - si no se hace así no habría forma de acceder a los miembros internos de la clase.

Espero haberte ayudado